# After updating to 15.10, my scopes projects fail to build for the unity-scope-tool. "error: g++ version must be 4.9!"

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, g++, cmake, scopes

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10. I have been making scopes, and many of my scopes projects stopped building after the upgrade.

My work process consists of running the scopes first in the unity-scope-tool.

The error in the Ubuntu SDK shows:

```
CMakeLists.txt:12: error: g++ version must be 4.9!
:-1: error: [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Lines 8-14 in CMakeLists.txt read:

```
# We require g++ 4.9, to avoid ABI breakage with earlier version.
set(cxx_version_required 4.9)
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION MATCHES "^${cxx_version_required}")
        message(FATAL_ERROR "g++ version must be ${cxx_version_required}!")
    endif()
endif()
```

And g++ version listed is `gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you need change the code in `CMakeLists.txt` line 8-14 to:

```
# We require at least g++ 4.9, to avoid ABI breakage with earlier versions.
set(cxx_version_required 4.9)
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS ${cxx_version_required})
        message(FATAL_ERROR "g++ version must be at least ${cxx_version_required}!")
    endif()
endif()
```

This is what is in the CMakeLists.txt of a new project, and will allow g++ versions higher than 4.9, save and rebuild the project and it should now get past that error.